# Implementing Google One Tap Login using angular

Tags: google-oauth, google-signin, google-authentication

**navbar.template.html**

```
   <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="832#################m921.apps.googleusercontent.com"
         data-cancel_on_tap_outside="false"
         data-login_uri="http://localhost:3010/auth/g-one-tap"
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse">
    </div>
```

The API get the response I am able to validate the user and return the validated JWT token, how can I capture the response and avoid the redirection of the page to `http://localhost:3010/auth/g-one-tap`

How can I us some click function to be used in typsecript file which can help in following the normal login flow which I am using earlier with google login button.

```
 public socialSignIn(responseData) {
         this.googleSubscription = this._globalService.googleLogin(responseData)
                .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        if (data['success']) {
                            const token = data['data']['token'];

                            if (this.platformId === 'browser') {
                               // login to save the token
                            }

                        }
                    },
                    error => {
                        console.log('error');
                    }
                );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/reference/html-reference#data-login_uri), you should not use both data-login_uri and data-callbck attributes at the same time.

You need to remove the data-login_uri attribute in you code.
And povide an implementation for the callback function (whose name is handleCredentialResponse in your code) if not yet.